# How do I pull app ratings from Google Play Store API?

Tags: android, api, google-play

Is there a way to access users' ratings and comments using Play Store API? Basically, I want to be able to sort apps by type, ratings (1-5) and certain keywords in the user comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Serach Playstore](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToSearchApps)

I think this is the solution:

```
String query = "rating:<rating>";
```